# Detect Errors to Improve Error Logging in Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Is there an elegant way to detect whether my google app engine application has had an error during a request to the application, and write out a much more detailed log when it does?

I have considerable "debug" level logging, but I would like to remove all that and only display the debug information when an error occurs.

Comment: You could write a custom log filter that does this. Is your end goal to reduce the amount of logging you produce for non-error requests?

Comment: Yes, Nick, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using webapp2 I recommend do it during a request with the next code:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(debug = os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev'), config=config.webapp2_config)

app.error_handlers[404] = handle_error
app.error_handlers[500] = handle_error
routes.add_routes(app)
```

You can see an example for that handle_error Here : 
https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate/lib/basehandler.py#L70

Comment: That's... so awesome. I didn't know that you could do anything close to that. I have many activities in my future now. =)

Comment: While useful, this doesn't really answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from the [LogService API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/overview) docs; Fetch and filter some request_logs (remember to include app_logs); For any req_log you can get the related app_logs. Any app_log have three property (time, level and message). What you looking for is message property.

```py
req_logs = logservice.fetch(start_time=time.time() - 3600,
                            end_time=time.time(),
                            minimum_log_level=logservice.LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,
                            include_app_logs=True)
for req_log in req_logs:
    for app_log in req_log.app_logs:
        print app_log.message
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to avoid logging unwanted info, not how to read the logs back.

Comment: I understood later. What do I do? I prefer to leave it for people who visit